# Cómo generar una cadena de formato de hora en Excel de modo que si pongo 0:30 solo muestre los minutos y si incluyo horas muestre hora y minutos

Tags: excel

Me preguntaba si era posible crear una cadena de formato de tiempo de manera que si en una celda incluyo 00:30 me muestre 30m y si incluyo alguna hora, como por ejemplo las 1:30, muestre 1h30m. Lo he intentado con algo así [<1]h\hmm\m;mm\m pero no va. No entiendo muy bien el [<1]. A mi entender es una condición de horas menor que 1, pero por vueltas que le dé no me devuelve el resultado que yo espero. Lo he intentado con GPT, pero que Dios nos libre de estas inteligencias (acabó con mi paciencia). Quizá no se pueda hacer con este tipo de cadenas de formato y haya que incluir alguna fórmula. A ver si me podéis orientar. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar un formato de celda para logarlo.

1. Selecciona las celdas, filas o columnas que deseas utilizar con este formato
2. Click derecho, formato de celda
3. Selecciona personalizado (Custom, no se como esté en español)
4. En la casilla de tipo (Type) escribe esto `[h]"h"m"m"`

Listo, esto tomará el primer número, luego adjuntará `h`, luego el segundo número y adjuntará `m`.

[image: Configuración]

Aquí te pongo una captura de pantalla con el dato que tiene y el que muestra

[image: Solución]

### Edición

Después de investigar un poco he encontrado la forma de hacer que las horas se muestren de forma condicional.

En Excel, un minúto es `0.00069444`, que se obtiene al saber que un día tiene 1440 minutos por lo que `1/1440 = 0.00069444`. Por lo tanto, una hora sería `0.041666` y si restamos un minuto sería `0.04097222` (59 minutos). Podemos utilizar un número que sea mayor a 59 minutos pero menor a 60 minutos, por ejemplo `0.0415`.

Con esto en mente lo único que tenemos que hacer es que nuestra condición de formato sea que si un número ingresado en la celda es mayor a `0.0415` muestre las horas y los minutos y si es menor a ese número entonces muestre únicamente los minutos.

```
[<0.0415][m]"m";[h]"h"m"m"
```

Al utilizar este formato podemos obtener el siguiente resultado

[image: Solución 2]

Comment: Pero ese formato no hace lo que yo quiero, ya que si en la celda escribo 00:30 me muestra 0h30m y debería mostrar solo 30m. A esto me refería cuando dije que si las horas son cero, solo muestre los minutos. Lo que tú has hecho, que está muy bien, ya lo había logrado.

Comment: Ah ya veo, deja investigo un poco

Comment: Listo @JoséManuel, edité la respuesta con la condición para esconder las horas en caso de que sean menores a 1.

Comment: Eres un verdadero crack. No se me hubiera ocurrido nunca. Gracias fiera.

Comment: ¿Y si los minutos fueran 0 que mostrara solo las horas? Por ejemplo: 1:00 que muestre 1h, conservando los formatos anteriores.

Comment: Te recomendaría intentarlo y realizar una nueva pregunta mostrando lo que intentaste en caso de no poder. Para lograr eso tuve que estar investigando e intentando un buen rato.

Comment: Lo intenté siguiendo el mismo criterio que analizaste en las líneas de arriba, pero no lo conseguí. No obstante, no es nada importante. Gracias de todos modos.